# Right align title text inside Material Design Card

Tags: css, material-design

I'm using a Material Design (MDL) card to display numeric values in the title. I want them to be aligned right but by default they are left aligned.  I've tried setting various styles but they all are ignored.  How can I right align the h2 in the card title?

```
  <div class="mdl-card card--count">
    <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand">
      <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">
        999
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text"><slot /></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text-align: right;` won't work as `.mdl-card__title` is using flex, so you have to change the `justify-content` property:

```css
  .mdl-card__title {
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f7ykzx1c/1/

Comment: Thank you. That works. I was applying that to the wrong element.